# How do I make the cubes up and down on the y axis following the curve and without rotating?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

How do I make the cubes up and  down on the y axis following the curve and without rotating with the same space distribuition?

I used beziercurve and clamp to do this.

[image: animation using clamp to constraint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AddObjectConstrain>>ClampTo.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I have lots of cubes. You used only one.